# Is there anyway to know if a website contains KML file?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, web-scraping, web-crawler, kml

I want to know if a website contains KML file(s). I have read through most of the KML related questions here and I understand that KML is just a XML file used by Google Maps or Google Earth API to mark geographic elements on the "earth browsers".

But still i want to know if there is any Google API or 3rd party API that takes in the website url and gives me answer like has KML file or No KML file ?

Can we scrap or crawl the whole website to get this information? Is it possible? Correct me if i am wrong anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ask Google by searching for something like this:

```
site:www.holidayautos.co.uk filetype:kml
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please give me more info regarding this - How can this be achieved programatically?

Comment: @VishwaKumar: Sorry, I don't know how you would do that programmatically.